# Troubleshoot Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services unexpected error

Tags: ssrs

I have an error implementing reports on reporting services from Visual Studio 2005 but I can do it from the Reports Manager

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Versión 10.0.5500.0.

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error reception.

How would I troubleshoot what the problem could be?

Comment: Check the logs for specific details on the error(s).

Comment: hi there, a quick search turned up [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/b6d522e4-d765-4b22-a35e-155a7616f1b7) (scroll to TennesseePaul's answer). Also, I don't have VS 2005 installed, but please make sure that you can deploy to a SQL Server 2008 target within VS 2005 and, if you can, make sure that you actually ***are*** deploying to a VS target. Also, try putting a slash after the target url.